# MongoDB Aggregate $lookup on array of object with additional field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two different collections (example below) *methods* & *items*. As for now, I'm using pre 3.6 vanilla aggregation query for `$lookup`:

[MongoPlayground Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/afX-FydIoTj)

```
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "items",
      localField: "reagents._id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "reagent_items"
    }
  }
```

The problem is that if I am using it, I miss `quantity` field (from `methods.reagents` embedded) during `$lookup` stage from original collection. For now, I return `quantity` right after `lookup` but as I heard, Mongo introduced from 3.6 a new syntax for `lookup` queries, so the question is:

> Can it solve my problem for receiving the following results:

```
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "Test",
    "reagent_items": [ // <= the exact schema of what I need after lookup
      {
        "_id": 1,
        "name": "ItemOne",
        "other": "field",
        "quantity": 2 //quantity field from original {array of objects} after lookup
      },
      {
        "_id": 2,
        "name": "ItemTwo",
        "other": "field",
        "quantity": 4 //quantity field from original {array of objects} after lookup
      }
    ],
    "reagents": [ //original reagents field here just for example, we could remove it
      {
        "_id": 1,
        "quantity": 2
      },
      {
        "_id": 2,
        "quantity": 4
      }
    ]
  }
```

**methods**

```
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "name": "Test",
      "reagents": [
        {
          _id: 1,
          quantity: 2
        },
        {
          _id: 2,
          quantity: 4
        }
      ]
    }
```

**items**

```
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "name": "ItemOne",
      "other": "field"
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "name": "ItemTwo",
      "other": "field"
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) along with [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) to find corresponding `reagent` for each `reagent_items` and the apply [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/index.html) to get one object:

```
db.methods.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "items",
            localField: "reagents._id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "reagent_items"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id:1,
            name: 1,
            reagents: 1,
            reagent_items: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$reagent_items",
                    as: "ri",
                    in: {
                        $mergeObjects: [
                            "$$ri",
                            {
                                $arrayElemAt: [ { $filter: { input: "$reagents", cond: { $eq: [ "$$this._id", "$$ri._id" ] } } }, 0 ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tm3fpE2tVzk)

Comment: Well, I have faced a problem with almost a relevant query: If I have index on `_id` field in collection that should been `lookuped` and the `reagents` array have `item_id` reversal order, for example not `[1,2,3] but [3,2,1], well `quantity` field can lose the correct `item` id after `$map` stage.

Comment: @AlexZeDim not sure if I understand your concern, there's a `{ $eq: [ "$$this._id", "$$ri._id" ] }` condition so order won't affect matching

Comment: yes, I haven't seen it at first, as for now, I am rechecking this thing. Well as for my problem it's hard to describe with only 500 symbols in comment, but I ruined my first DB because of wrong schema pattern.

Comment: Can you please answer this question?   
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64661069/mongodb-populating-field-on-aggregation-query @mickl