# How to do `lookup` or `join` using aggregation function without removing the original attributes with mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have this object that coming from mongodb

```
{
        "shaufel_customer_union_id": 3,
        "_id": "5ea97ad7f186dc9bddd17293",
        "shaufel_customers": [
            {
                "_id": "5ea978745f21919cbf465405",
                "customer_id": "1",
                "percent": 100,
                "customer": "5ea97655f186dc9bddd17292"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5ea978745f21919cbf465405",
                "customer_id": "2",
                "percent": 50,
                "customer": "5ea97b1bf186dc9bddd17294"
            }
        ],
        "createdAt": "2020-04-29T12:52:04.602Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-04-29T12:52:04.602Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "id": "5ea97ad7f186dc9bddd17293"
    }
```

What I am trying to do is to `$lookup` for customer inside shaufel_customers for each object so that what I am doing to do that

```
   const aggregate = await CustomerUnionCustomer.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'customers',
                localField: 'shaufel_customers.customer',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'shaufel_customers',
            }
        },


    ])
```

Now the problem with this code is that it joins the customers' documents but it removes the `percent` attribute resulting this

```
   {
        "_id": "5ea97ad7f186dc9bddd17293",
        "shaufel_customer_union_id": 3,
        "shaufel_customers": [
            {
                "_id": "5ea97655f186dc9bddd17292",
                "migration_customer_id": "3"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5ea97b1bf186dc9bddd17294",
                "migration_customer_id": "5"
            }
        ],
        "createdAt": "2020-04-29T12:52:04.602Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-04-29T12:52:04.602Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

So how should I join the customers document with keeping the `percent` attribute using mongodb aggregate function.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61514375/mongodb-aggregate-lookup-on-array-of-object-with-additional-field/61514436#61514436 ?

Comment: @mickl, it works man! thanks a lot, the issue is solved