# Mongoose: Populate path which is not an individual collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have two collections, let's call it collection A & B.
Inside collection A, I have an array of Objects with structure like -

**Collection A**

```
[{
   _id: "<mongo_id>",
   department: "gastro",
   doctors: [{
     _id: "<mongo_id>",
     name: "Lorem Ipsum",
     type: "Surgeon",
     age: 45
    },{
     _id: "<mongo_id>",
     name: "Dolor Sit Amet",
     type: "General Physician",
     age: 36
   }]
}]
```

Then inside the collection B, I have this array object _id from collection A, as a reference.
let say -

**Collection B**

```
[{
  _id: "<mongo_id>",
  name: "John Doe",
  assignedDoc: "<_id_of_doctor_from_collection_A>",
  appointmentDate: 2020-08-29T12:09:18.153+00:00
 },{
  _id: "<mongo_id>",
  name: "Jane Doe",
  assignedDoc: "<_id_of_doctor_from_collection_A>",
  appointmentDate: 2020-08-29T12:09:18.153+00:00
}]
```

Now I want to populate the _id of **assignedDoc** in collection B, to show the doc details from collection A.
Anyone knows, how can we do that?

Basically, I don't want to create a separate collection for doctors, as that won't be nosql approach as much I know. That will be kind of sql relatioship approach.
Or If I'm wrong or my approach is not correct, please guide me.

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61514375/mongodb-aggregate-lookup-on-array-of-object-with-additional-field/61514436#61514436 ?

Comment: Let me check @mickl thanks for the reference answer :)